# Generating UUID for _id while PUT to elasticsearch causes 400

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to `elasticsearch` and I am not sure why I am getting this message when I try to PUT some data into my index. I want to create my own ID's so I generated my own UUIDs.

My index exists:

$ curl {IP}:{PORT}/_cat/indices?v
health status index   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size 
yellow open   tracer    5   1          0            0       795b           795b 
yellow open   .kibana   1   1          1            0      3.2kb          3.2kb

```
$ curl -XPUT http://{IP}:{PORT}/tracer/poster/b9d9fj2c-69ea-47f0-94e1-a6a3caecd097?pretty -d {"test": 1}
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason" : "failed to parse"
    } ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "failed to parse",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "json_e_o_f_exception",
      "reason" : "Unexpected end-of-input within/between Object entries\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.InputStreamStreamInput@572153d0; line: 1, column: 13]"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `?pretty`?

Comment: Also, I think you need to wrap the JSON with single quotes, so '{ "test": 1 }'

Comment: @OrWeinberger okay this worked! Now I have to figure out why it doesn't work in my code...

Comment: @OrWeinberger you can answer teh question and I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to wrap your JSON input with single quotes

```
user@host ~ $ curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/test/test/1?pretty -d {"test": 1}
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason" : "failed to parse"
    } ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "failed to parse",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "json_e_o_f_exception",
      "reason" : "Unexpected end-of-input within/between Object entries\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.InputStreamStreamInput@370eef58; line: 1, column: 13]"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 2
```

And now with single quotes:

```
user@host ~ $ curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/test/test/1?pretty -d '{"test": 1}'
{
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "test",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_version" : 1,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "created" : true
}
```